# Facebook Graph API - Adding tab

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to add a tab trought the facebook js api, and it fails:

1. Login with permissions:

   ```
   FB.login(function(response) {
       console.log(response);
   }, {
       scope: 'publish_actions, manage_pages'
   });
   ```

   <strike>FB.login(function(response) {console.log(response);
       }, {perms:'read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access'});</strike>
2. reading pages to get token:

   FB.api(
       "/me/accounts",
       function (response) {
           if (response && !response.error) {
               console.log(response)
           }
       }
   );
3. adding a tab, for example, these two methods:

a.

```
FB.api(
    "/{page_id}/tabs/",
"POST",
    {
        "app_id": "{app_id}",
  access_token: "{token}" 
    },
    function (response) {
            console.log(response)
    }
);
```

I get response:

```
Object {success: true}
```

b. tried directly:

```
jimdoGen002.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/{page_id}/tabs?app_id={app_id}&access_token=token&callback=?', function(r){console.log(r)})
```

I get response, array with the tabs the user page has, but without my new tab.

4. going to the user page - no new tab.

My questions:

1. what am I missing? why do I get sucess but cant get the tab?
2. if its because the review of "manage_pages" by facebook is not complete yet - why do I get success?
3. if the above - how can I test manage pages BEFORE I post it to facebook review?
4. Can I add a tab WITHOUT an app inside? just an iframe url?

Thanks in advance,
Lior.

(to make it all simple:)

```
FB.api(
    "/me/accounts",
    function (response) {
        var token = response.data[0].access_token;
        var id = response.data[0].id;
        console.log(response.data[0].name);

        FB.api(
            id + '/tabs',
            "POST",
            {
                "app_id": {app_id},
                "access_token": token
            },
            function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                FB.api(
                    id + '/tabs/{app_id}',
                    function (response) {
                        console.log(response)
                    },
                    {
                        access_token: token
                    },
                    function(response) {
                        console.log(response)
                    }
                );
            }
        );

    }
);
```

result:

my page
Object {success: true}
Object {data: Array[2]} - none is my app.

Comment: According to your login code you are not even asking for manage_pages permission. `read_stream` your app will not be allowed to use, and `publish_stream` and `offline_access` don’t even exist any more. And `perms` is the wrong parameter name altogether, that should be `scope`. Instead of copy&pasting code that is way old, you should read the documentation on how to do this properly using current code.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe I was actually using the correct one, and did a copy paste to here from an old code I had. Its still doesnt work. I am getting a success response, but cant see the tab.